# Combine rows in R

Tags: r

In R I have a dataset `data`

```
tts 21y
ttt 52k
...
```

These are all strings and `dim(data)=1000 2`. I want to combine the rows so I can get a new data `newdata`

```
tts21y
ttt52k
...
```

Here we have taken both strings in a row and combined them into a longer string. How can I do this in R ?

Comment: `with(df, paste(columnname1, columnname2))`

Comment: `paste(data$X1,data$X2,sep="")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the following:

```
paste0(data[,1], data[,2])
```